# Looking for a more dynamic designer TypeConverter serialization in a VS10 .NET form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, serialization, design-time

I have a list of a class which I serialize to the designer generated code with the following code:

```
internal class TargetSettingsConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor) || base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor) && value is ControlListManager.TargetSettings)
        {
            ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(ControlListManager.TargetSettings).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(object), typeof(string), typeof(DisplayModes), typeof(bool), typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(int) });
            var target = value as ControlListManager.TargetSettings;
            var descriptor = new InstanceDescriptor(constructor, new[] { target.Target, target.Text, target.DisplayMode, target.Fade, target.HideTimeout, target.PaddingX, target.PaddingY }, true);
            return descriptor;
        }
        if (culture == null) { culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture; }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

This works well so far, but what bothers me is that I have to specify the types and values individually.

My first idea was to use *GetConstructor**s**()* instead. But then to problem of the values still remains. I'm really confused about this problem since I actually write the function without knowing the amount of parameters - or only if it is "hardcoded".

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done better?

Edit: The data class

```
    [TypeConverter(typeof(TargetSettingsConverter))]
    public class TargetSettings : IEquatable<TargetSettings>
    {
        public object Target = new { };
        public string Text;
        public DisplayModes DisplayMode = DisplayModes.FollowXY;
        public bool Fade = true;
        public int HideTimeout;
        public int PaddingX;
        public int PaddingY;
        public bool Equals(TargetSettings other)
        {
            return other != null && (Target.Equals(other.Target));
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) { return false; }
            TargetSettings objAsPart = obj as TargetSettings;
            if (objAsPart == null) { return false; }
            return Equals(objAsPart);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Target.GetHashCode();
        }
        public TargetSettings(object target, string text = "", DisplayModes displayMode = DisplayModes.FollowXY, bool fade = true, int hideTimeout = 0, int paddingX = 0, int paddingY = 0)
        {
            Target = target;
            Text = text;
            DisplayMode = displayMode;
            Fade = fade;
            HideTimeout = hideTimeout;
            PaddingX = paddingX;
            PaddingY = paddingY;
        }
    }
```

Comment: based on my test, I can not find the class ControlListManager.TargetSettings. Is it  a class you created by yourself? If so, please provide it.

Comment: Sure I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, you want to make your code more dynamic for the types and values.

Since the types and values you want to convert are all field types. I recommend that you use the reflection to do it.

You can get all the field types as the following:

```
 Type []tarr = typeof(TargetSettings).GetFields().Select(i => i.FieldType).ToArray();
 ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(TargetSettings).GetConstructor(tarr);
```

You can get all the field values as the following:

```
object []oarr= typeof(TargetSettings).GetFields().Select(i => i.GetValue(target)).ToArray();
var descriptor = new InstanceDescriptor(constructor, oarr, true);
```

Full code:

```
internal class TargetSettingsConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {
            return destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor) || base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor) && value is TargetSettings)
            {
                Type []tarr = typeof(TargetSettings).GetFields().Select(i => i.FieldType).ToArray();
                ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(TargetSettings).GetConstructor(tarr);
                var target = value as TargetSettings;
                object []oarr= typeof(TargetSettings).GetFields().Select(i => i.GetValue(target)).ToArray();
                var descriptor = new InstanceDescriptor(constructor, oarr, true);
                return descriptor;
            }
            if (culture == null) { culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture; }
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }


    [TypeConverter(typeof(TargetSettingsConverter))]
    public class TargetSettings : IEquatable<TargetSettings>
    {
        public object Target = new { };
        public string Text;
        public DisplayModes DisplayMode = DisplayModes.FollowXY;
        public bool Fade = true;
        public int HideTimeout;
        public int PaddingX;
        public int PaddingY;
        public bool Equals(TargetSettings other)
        {
            return other != null && (Target.Equals(other.Target));
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) { return false; }
            TargetSettings objAsPart = obj as TargetSettings;
            if (objAsPart == null) { return false; }
            return Equals(objAsPart);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Target.GetHashCode();
        }
        public TargetSettings(object target, string text = "", DisplayModes displayMode = DisplayModes.FollowXY, bool fade = true, int hideTimeout = 0, int paddingX = 0, int paddingY = 0)
        {
            Target = target;
            Text = text;
            DisplayMode = displayMode;
            Fade = fade;
            HideTimeout = hideTimeout;
            PaddingX = paddingX;
            PaddingY = paddingY;
        }
    }

    public enum DisplayModes
    {
        FollowXY

    }
```