# Problem with serialization order (designer code) in .NET VS win form project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2010, serialization

According to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64714234/looking-for-a-more-dynamic-designer-typeconverter-serialization-in-a-vs10-net-f):

I got a list and a selected index which I serialize:

```
public interface IControlListManager
{
    List<ControlListManager.TargetSettings> TargetList { get; set; }
    int SelectedIndex { get; set; }
}
```

Inside designer.cs I got the following serialized code:

```
//...
controlListManager1.SelectedIndex = 0;
controlListManager1.TargetList.Add(new ControlListManager.TargetSettings(this, "", DisplayModes.FollowXY, true, 0, 0, 0));
controlListManager1.TargetList.Add(new ControlListManager.TargetSettings(this.InfoPanel, "", DisplayModes.FollowXY, true, 0, 0, 0));
controlListManager1.TargetList.Add(new ControlListManager.TargetSettings(this.InfoText, "", DisplayModes.FollowXY, true, 0, 0, 0));
controlListManager1.TargetList.Add(new ControlListManager.TargetSettings(this.HLine, "", DisplayModes.FollowXY, true, 0, 0, 0));
controlListManager1.TargetList.Add(new ControlListManager.TargetSettings(this.LogiDevType, "", DisplayModes.FollowXY, true, 0, 0, 0));
controlListManager1.TargetList.Add(new ControlListManager.TargetSettings(this.LogiDevSetBtn, "", DisplayModes.FollowXY, true, 0, 0, 0));
controlListManager1.TargetList.Add(new ControlListManager.TargetSettings(this.SystrayContextMenu, "", DisplayModes.FollowXY, true, 0, 0, 0));
controlListManager1.TargetList.Add(new ControlListManager.TargetSettings(this.restoreToolStripMenuItem, "", DisplayModes.FollowXY, true, 0, 0, 0));
controlListManager1.TargetList.Add(new ControlListManager.TargetSettings(this.exitToolStripMenuItem, "", DisplayModes.FollowXY, true, 0, 0, 0));
controlListManager1.TargetList.Add(new ControlListManager.TargetSettings(this.panel1, "", DisplayModes.FollowXY, true, 0, 0, 0));
controlListManager1.TargetList.Add(new ControlListManager.TargetSettings(this.IdentifierInput, "", DisplayModes.FollowXY, true, 0, 0, 0));
controlListManager1.TargetList.Add(new ControlListManager.TargetSettings(this.ExitButton, "", DisplayModes.FollowXY, true, 0, 0, 0));
controlListManager1.TargetList.Add(new ControlListManager.TargetSettings(this.IdentifierCheckbox, "", DisplayModes.FollowXY, true, 0, 0, 0));
controlListManager1.TargetList.Add(new ControlListManager.TargetSettings(this.SaveLogFile, "", DisplayModes.FollowXY, true, 0, 0, 0));
//...
```

The problem is that `SelectedIndex` should be after the list because well it represents the index of the list.

How can I tell the designer to put it after the list?

Comment: [ISupportInitialize Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize). Better description here: [The role of BeginInit() and EndInit() methods in Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30464280/7444103)

Comment: Merci. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Mhhh. Just a little question. The guy in the answer say that it will set alphabetically by default. Could I change the var name of SelectedIndex to ZSelectedIndex? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I don't want to mess around with BeginInit() and EndInit() methods (what I really should) and found out, that it's really fact, that the serializer order is alphabetical.

I renamed `SelectedIndex` to `ZSelectedIndex`. Funny and dirty - but quick solution.